# Transaction Time out error C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#

**Database Type** : SQL server 2008 R2

**Issue description:**

There are two machines. One is server machine(OS- Windows server Enterprise) another one is client machine(OS- Windows 7 professional). In Both machines SQL server 2008 R2 is installed.

Same database is being restored in both SQL servers. A process(consists of stored procedures) is running with in transaction scope from the application(Language : C# .NET) and application access the database.

In server, its taking long time to execute the procedures(above 5 minutes). In client machine its taking only 1 - 2 minutes. In Both machines, database used is same. Transaction Timeout value too declared same (5 minutes)

**Server properties:**
[image]

**Client machine properties**
[image]

**SQL server Properties - Server:**
[image]

**SQL server properties - client machine**
[image]

Please share your thoughts. Any idea for this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: What additional workloads (both Sql Server and any other service, like file shares, IIS etc) the server is doing? What kind of storage the server has? Are the execution plans the same?

Comment: Get the query monitor going on the server to see what other work it is doing, likewise the OS process monitor.